# How to display (and format) datetime data in Qtableview with pyside2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I am trying to display datetime values in a QTableView. I have found this working pyside2 example (scroll down) for string and float type data:

[PySide + QTableView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411101/pyside-qtableview-example)

What would I need to change within the table model so that I could display datetime data. How could this data be formatted to be displayed for example like '01.05.2019'.

I do NOT want to convert the datetime data to string beforehand since then the data cannot be sorted in a meaningful way when clicking in the table header...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the data as a `QDateTime` (or `QDate` or `QTime`).  The `QTableView` should be fine with that.

If you want to format the date differently then it starts to get complicated:  you'll need to convert it to a string using your own formatting.  Then to get the sorting right, you'll need to return the original date data in some other role (Qt::UserRole) and set that to be the sort role, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491803/1295678) (which also suggests an alternative approach using a delegate).

Comment: Oh yeah. So simple. Stupid me :-)